# C++ & Xcode: Apple Mach-O Linker error?

Tags: c++, xcode, oop, linker

I'm  studying C++ from an online course (Stanford CS106B via iTunes U) and I'm trying to work with code that was designed for Xcode 3 in version 4.3.2

I suspect there are fundamental changes in 4.3.2, therefore fundamental incompatibilities with this old code.

The following screen shots illustrate the C++ code I'm trying to compile and the errors Xcode 4.3.2 is reporting.

There's probably a simple answer to this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

If someone could explain to me what's going wrong in newb terms that would be awesome!

My simple program:
[image: program]

And the error I get when running it:
[image: error]

Comment: 1. It's Xcode, and not X-Code, XCode, CXode or anything else. 2. Xcode and its version has nothing to do with this error -- this is a linker error. Xcode is not the linker. 3. You've most probably run into the problem of name mangling (just google this expression).

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks - Ive removed that dash! I have Googled the expression but have not come up with anything Ive found very helpful, hence my post here

Comment: OK, so basically the problem may be (due to wrong compiler settings) that C++ uses a different symbol and function naming convention that of plain C. That means, an object file produced by a C++ compiler can only be linked using the correct corresponding C++ linker flags -- probably you should have a look at your compiler and its options.

Comment: Also how is the compiler happy with the use of `cout` and `endl` without a `using namespace std;`?  That must be within the `genlib.h` or `simpio.h` file, which is bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be compiling and linking in the source file that contains the function `GetInteger()`.

**EDIT** The issue with `main()` is due to it being defined in your `genlib.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe. I've added the libraries properly using the Build Phases tab (something I knew nothing about before). Thats gotten rid of the GetInteger() issue, but the others remain. It wont let me use your code above either. It says there are too many arguments

Comment: @MeltingDog Yeah to be honest I wasn't sure about my suggestion with `main`; I've always been able to use the form that you provide in your original code.  I'm not sure what is going on there.  Can you please perform a search for "main" in your project (4th tab in lefthand pane) and see if there is anything that redefines it?

Comment: thanks. The search for 'main' reveals * main() function in the genlib.cpp file....not entirely sure what this means